# ASP.NET AJAX: Creating a postback

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax

I would like to cause a post back that occurs only once by inserting some AJAX into the page after a specific event occurs.

Currently I have:

```
string script = "<script language='Javascript'>" +
                                    "__doPostBack('GetSpreadsheet', '');" +
                                "</script>";

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "DownloadExcel", script);
```

However, after I do this, every post back has an event target of GetSpreadsheet instead of just the first one.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is that code residing? In an event handler?

Comment: @joerage: Yes. When the given event occurs, it inserts the script. Then I check on the PageLoad eventhandler for the EventTarget of the request.  However, even if I click on another button, the EventTarget remains "GetSpreadsheet".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method (Control, Type, String, String, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx).

In the remarks, you will find this text which explains what you are after.

> Startup script blocks that are
>   registered by using this method are
>   sent to the page only when the control
>   that is registering the block is
>   inside an UpdatePanel control that is
>   being updated.

Comment: I am using this code in a UserControl.  Should I put the user control inside an update panel?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the IsStartUpScriptRegistered() method before registering your script.

```
if (!(Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("DownloadExcel")) )
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "DownloadExcel", script);
```